# Keyerror when trying to add decimal points to floats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the dataset I'm dealing with some values of latitude and longitude are missing decimal points, and for this, I created a function to deal with the issue.

I get the error on line 6:

`data.loc[data[lat_col] > 90, lat_col] /= 1000`

And I would assume line 7 would give me the same error.

Error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([55.6902,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0, 55.6775,     0.0,     0.0,\n                  0.0,     0.0,     0.0,\n              ...\n                  0.0,     0.0,     0.0, 55.9379, 55.9379, 55.9379, 55.9379,\n              55.9379, 55.9378,     0.0],\n             dtype='float64', length=143820)] are in the [columns]"
```

Data

```
    latitude    longitude
0   12.57220    55.69020
1   0.00000     0.00000
2   0.00000     0.00000
4   0.00000     0.00000
5   12.57700    55.67750
6   0.00000     0.00000
7   0.00000     0.00000
8   0.00000     0.00000
9   0.00000     0.00000
10  0.00000     0.00000
11  0.00000     0.00000
12  0.00000     0.00000
14  12.58440    55.67970
15  12.58230    55.67930
16  12.58478    55.67996
17  12.58477    55.67996
18  12.59170    55.67980
...
```

Function

```py
def clean_latitude_longitude(data, lat_col, lon_col):
    """Fixes lat & lon values, some of them are missing decimal points.
    """
    #data = data.copy()

    data.loc[data[lat_col] > 90, lat_col] /= 1000
    data.loc[data[lon_col] > 180, lon_col] /= 1000
    return data

dff = clean_latitude_longitude(df, df["latitude"], df["longitude"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error it's because you are passing as argument an entire Series, instead of the column name, so the function `loc` will lookup in the columns names, the values of the column you are passing, and there are not columns named like that, that's the reason of the error, so try to change:

```
clean_latitude_longitude(df, df["latitude"], df["longitude"])
```

To:

```
clean_latitude_longitude(df, "latitude", "longitude")
```

Comment: I swear this place makes me feel stupid sometimes :D

Comment: Dont't say that haha. You know that in this site we are all learning :) @doomdaam